# UIStoryboard constraints on UIView

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, uiview, constraints

I have a view on top of my viewcontroller, its height is 64.

I need this view stays same size in all screen size 3.5" , 4" , 4,7" and 5,5".

The result I am taking is as in screenshots.

What should I do?[image]

After fixing height to 64 it looks like this ;[image]

Comment: Are you using autolayout? can you show us the constraints if you do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add Fixed Height to your Headerview like this , check in below image .

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Fix Height of your view

Leading  : 0

Top : 0

trailing : 0

Answer (score 0):

Pin the height for wAny hAny size classes.